# I want use a child theme to change wordpress dashboard by code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize the display of the **red box** and add some listening events to the **green box** check box.
[Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNip4.png)

I try to write my own js file to control the above listening event, but my js file doesn't work
my php code :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'multi_child_style' );
function multi_child_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
```

JS Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Comment: [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) is for frontend use. for backend use you should use [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/). Read the documentation on the given links for more details.